# javascript regex to match 0, 0-9 but not 0-, 0-9-, 0-9x

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying match text with patterns `0, 0-9` but not `0-, 0-9-, 0x, 0-9x`.

I tried these `/^(\d-?\d?)^[-a-zA-Z]$/ and /^(\d-?\d?)(?!-)$/`. Non of these fully satisfy my need.

Could you provide with better regex with explanation on how its working? Thanx for taking time to help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below regex. This won't allow any characters other than digit or hyphen and this asserts that if any hyphen is present then it must be at the middle not at the start or at the end.

```
^\d(?:-\d)?$
```

**OR**

```
^\d+(?:-\d+)?$
```

`\d+` matches one or more digits. So this allows strings like `34-56` also.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fA7xB8/3)

```
/^\d+(?:-\d+)?$/.test('0-9');
//=>true
/^\d+(?:-\d+)?$/.test('0');
//=>true
/^\d+(?:-\d+)?$/.test('0x');
//=>false
```